# separate string from numeric string pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I am working on android project. I am getting sensor values from Accelerometer and Gyro sensor which are in the form A1 A2 A3 G1 G2 G3 for eg. consider string pattern"-553 39 -415 -540 168 -209".So how to extract -553,39,-415 values from this string pattern and assign to variables A1,A2,A3 and similarly extract -540,168,-209 and assign to G1,G2,G3.I have converted it into  ArrayList But when reading values from it the app crashes. Any other Ideas to get result?

Using ArrayList:

```
    String str= "-553 39 -415 -540 168 -209";
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
               String x1 = myList.get(0);
               String y1 = myList.get(1);
               String z1 = myList.get(2);
               String x2 = myList.get(3);
               String y2 = myList.get(4);
               String z2 = myList.get(5);
               Log.d("Accel",x1 );
               Log.d("Accel",y1 );
               Log.d("Accel",z1 );
               Log.d("Gyro",x2 );
               Log.d("Gyro",y2 );
               Log.d("Gyro",z2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split("\\s")` to split the string.

```
    String str = "-553 39 -415 -540 168 -209";
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s"));
    String x1 = myList.get(0);
    String y1 = myList.get(1);
    String z1 = myList.get(2);
    String x2 = myList.get(3);
    String y2 = myList.get(4);
    String z2 = myList.get(5);
    Log.d("Accel",x1 );
    Log.d("Accel",y1 );
    Log.d("Accel",z1 );
    Log.d("Gyro",x2 );
    Log.d("Gyro",y2 );
    Log.d("Gyro",z2 );
```

Comment: This isn't an answer unless you *explain* what you're doing. "coder" is clueless. Give him clues.

Comment: @coder check updated answer, it is working fine with me.